# Getting device properties (warp_size etc) in PyCuda : doesn't work

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I am doing a PyCuda code and I would like to get the property of the graphic card (like size of warps, max threads per block etc).

So I went to this page : https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html

And I saw this :

[image]

Then I wrote in my code the following :

```
import time
import numpy as np
from pycuda import driver, compiler, gpuarray, tools
import math

# -- initialize the device
import pycuda.autoinit

print(pycuda.driver.device_attribute.WARP_SIZE)
```

But the print returns : WARP_SIZE

Indeed he returns a str containing "WARP_SIZE" and not the integer representing the warp size.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

What you are printing out is the enumeration which needs to be passed to the device interface to retrieve that attribute. You want something like this:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from pycuda import driver, compiler, gpuarray, tools
import math


# -- initialize the device
import pycuda.autoinit

dev = pycuda.autoinit.device
print(dev.get_attribute(pycuda.driver.device_attribute.WARP_SIZE))
print(dev.get_attribute(pycuda.driver.device_attribute.MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X))
```

which does this:

```
$ python device_attr.py 
32
1024
```